# getApplicationContext is null when using MultiDex

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-multidex

I need to switch my app to an multidexApp, but unfortunaly, some of my packages use my application context for saving files or other things .. But when i used `android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication` my context become null.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (App.context() == null) {            // App.context() call getApplicationContext()
        Log.e(TAG, " App context is null"); // -> Always null
    }

    ...
}
```

Like this guy : [Using MultiDexApplication causes applicationContext to become null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835217/using-multidexapplication-causes-applicationcontext-to-become-null) , its the same problem (I think), I tryed to simply restart AS, create a new project and copy/paste some files... nothing works.

My application is really big so I can't rewrite lines of codes, and I'm forced to use multidex

Comment: `im forced to use multidex` why? By the by show logcat

Comment: Im using SygicSDK embedded integration, so to avoid manifest merge errors and because : https://www.sygic.com/developers/professional-navigation-sdk/android/getting-started/embedded-integration-using-android-studio